# Inverse limits are projective limits

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, limits-colimits

I'm learning about projective limits, and one definiton (which you will find on Wikipedia) is done with a projective system over groups, call it $(X_i, \varphi_{i,j})$. And they define the inverse limit as:
$$\varprojlim Y_i = \\{ y\in \prod\limits_{i\in I} Y_i\mid y_i = \varphi_{ij} (y_j) \text{ for all } i\leq j\in I \\}$$
My question now, or more accurately my request, is if anyone here knows of a resource, be it a textbook or otherwise, that shows that the above definition is in fact a projective limit, in the universal property sense of the term. Just a point in the right direction would be super appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is in many books on category theory, e.g., in chapter 5 of Tom Leinster's *Basic Category Theory* freely available at https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375

Comment: @Jochen thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.